# how to change the colour of a certain sentence in IOS UILabel?

Tags: ios, uilabel

Suppose I have text like this in a label

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
>   nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
>   sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
>   rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem
>   ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
>   sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
>   dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam
>   et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
>   takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

How do I change the colour of the the sentence "At vero eos et..." starting in the second line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible with the UILabel class. However, it wouldn't be too hard to do this with some simple HTML in a UIWebView.

```
[myWebView loadHTMLString:@"Some normal text. <font color=\"red\">Some red text.</font>" baseURL:nil]
```

Let me know if this works well for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with a standard `UILabel`. You'd either have to use multiple `UILabel`s or take a look at CoreText which would also do what you want - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html.

Comment: can I just highlight certain text (say one sentence) and have a specific colour for that?

Comment: No, you can't do that with a `UILabel`. You need to either construct the layout yourself with multiple `UILabel`s (which would be a pain for the layout you're describing), use CoreText or as @josh-rosen points out, use a web view.